# Turn Auto-Lock Off from an Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, settings

Users want Auto-Lock turned off while using my navigation utility. Is it possible to control Auto-Lock from an application?

[also, "How to stop your iPad from sleeping or suspending"]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will prevent the screen to dim and go to sleep.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```